# Get only pricing details from a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string that looks like this:

`string = 5ft - +$28.87`

I need to get the price out of that string, (making sure not to grab the 5).

So something like this:

`money = 28.87`

The string also sometimes might look like this:

`3ft - Free`

In which case it should return 0.

I tried this:

`money=parseFloat(string.substring(string.indexOf('$')+1));`

That seems to work except in the case of the `3ft - Free` it returns `3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> That seems to work except in the case of the 3ft - Free it returns 3

Of course it does, `indexOf` returns `-1` if the string isn't found. `-1 + 1` is `0`, so you're doing `substring(0)`, and the doing `parseFloat` on the result.

Put a branch in:

```
var index = string.indexOf('$');
money = index === -1 ? 0 : parseFloat(string.substring(index + 1));
```

Comment: @Talon: Surely that was obvious? If `indexOf` returns `-1` when the string isn't found?

Comment: Sorry nevermind, the ternary expression was throwing me off, works perfect now.  Thanks for your help.